# How to integrate a kibana plugin inside a dashboard?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am developing a kibana plugin in 7.17. I have used the script generate_plugin, that generate a plugin in app level not a visualization. It is possible to integrate that plugin inside a dashboard?

Map is also an application and is possible to use it inside a dashboard.

Comment: Hi there, please provide more details to reproduce your issue~